# Creating a Dichotomous Variable in R

Tags: r, variables, if-statement

I have imported a csv file which contains 2044 observations of 3 variables, CASEID, DEGREE, and HRS1.
The first 6 observations appeared as:

```
head(degree.wrk)
  CASEID DEGREE HRS1
1  53044    3   55
2  53045    3   45
3  53046     0   -1
4  53047     0   -1
5  53048     0   -1
6  53049     0   -1
```

I want to create a dichotomous variable based on DEGREE which determines if a person has earned at
least a bachelors degree. According to the codebook, DEGREE values greater than or equal to 3 indicate a minimum of Bachelor's Degree earned. If the minimum has been met, I want it to return "Yes", if not, I want it to return "No". I used the ifelse() function and it appears to have worked, but I wonder if replacing the numerical value of DEGREE with the YES or NO category label is the correct action when seeking to create a dichotomous variable, or if I have simply replaced or recoded an existing variable.

The results of the ifelse() function are as follows:

```
degree.wrk$DEGREE <- ifelse(degree.wrk$DEGREE >=3,
                             c("Yes"),
                             c("No"))
head(degree.wrk)
  CASEID DEGREE HRS1
1  53044    Yes   55
2  53045    Yes   45
3  53046     No   -1
4  53047     No   -1
5  53048     No   -1
6  53049     No   -1
```

Any advice as to whether or not I adequately created a dichotomous variable using this method?

Comment: There are plenty ways of creating a dichotomous variable and `ifelse` is one of them (probably the most efficient way would be something like `transform(degree.wrk, DEGREE = DEGREE >= 3)`). What is your question exactly? What are you going to do with this variable?

Comment: Thanks David! I wasn't sure if I could use the ifelse function to create a dichotomous variable. It seemed like it worked, but since this is my first time using the function, I wasn't sure what it was supposed to look like in the end. I will be conducting a hypothesis test for the difference in the number of hours worked for the two groups. (those with a minimum of a bachelor's degree and those with less than a bachelors degree)

Comment: To help you look for help on this, it's worth knowing that in R, rather than looking for the term "dichotomous", you want the term "logical".